# How can I check what mining algorithm does an altcoin use?

Tags: altcoin, miner-configuration, algorithms

Where in the sourcecode files can this be checked?

For example, lets get a specific coin:

Chronon
https://github.com/ChrononGroup/Chronon

In what file can one check the mining algorithm?

Comment: Your question is very broad, where in the source code varies for every altcoin.

Comment: If my below answer successfully answered your question, could you please accept it so the question isn't left open? And if it hasn't, can you help me edit/add to it so that it does?

Comment: Please accept the answer that was given or ask a more specific question if you are not satisfied with the answer. Keeping the question open leads everyone to believe it hasn't been adequately addressed.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the coin, you can find the PoW algorithm by perusing the source code of the coin. For the coin you referenced, reviewing the directory Chronon/src/pow.cpp one can see the algorithm is X11.